# Are Java String Objects an Array of Chars?

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, chars

I am new to java and trying to understand the essentials and fundamentals of the language.

***Is it accurate to state that Java string objects are intrinsically a class defined as an immutable array of chars?***

I ask this as I'm a bit confused by the spec in comparison to char arrays and the string class...

[JLS 10.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.9)

> 10.9 An Array of Characters is Not a String
>   In the Java programming language, unlike C, an array of char is not a String,
>   and neither a String nor an array of char is terminated by '\u0000' (the NUL
>   character).
>   A String object is immutable, that is, its contents never change, while an array of
>   char has mutable elements.
>   The method toCharArray in class String returns an array of characters containing
>   the same character sequence as a String. The class StringBuffer implements useful
>   methods on mutable arrays of characters.

[JLS 4.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3)

> 4.3.3 The Class String Instances of class String represent sequences of Unicode code points.

Comment: thanks for posting the question. i always tought, String as an array of chars. :) .. +1

Comment: @chaitanya10: regarding your question on my now deleted answer: an object is *an instance* of a class. It's not a class. A class and an object are two different things.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is it accurate to state that Java string objects are intrinsically a class defined as an immutable array of chars?

No. A Java String object is (currently - it's an implementation detail which I gather may be changing) a class *containing* a few fields:

- A `char[]` containing the actual characters
- A starting index into the array
- A length
- A cached hash code, lazily computed

The reason for the index and length is that several strings can contain references to the same `char[]`. This is used by some operations such as `substring` (in many implementations, anyway).

The important thing is the API for `String` though - which is very different to the API for an array. It's the API you would think of when you take the JLS definition into account: a `String` represents a sequence of Unicode code points. So you can take a subsequence (`Substring`), find a given subsequence (`indexOf`), convert it to an upper case sequence etc.

In fact the JLS would be slightly more accurate to call it a sequence of UTF-16 code units; it's entirely possible to construct a string which isn't a *valid* sequence of Unicode code points, e.g. by including one half of a "surrogate pair" of UTF-16 code units but not the other. There are parts of the API which *do* deal with the `String` in terms of code units, but frankly *most* developers spend *most* of the time treating strings as if non-BMP characters didn't exist.

Comment: Nice answer. Could you shed some light on "String represent sequences of Unicode code points" and how it is different from char[] containing the actual character? May be non native english speaker confusion?

Comment: +1 accepted - I think this clearly answers my question. Thanks for the concise answer.