# why i can't make operators on 8- and 16-Bit Integrals

Tags: c#, variables

why i can't make operators on 8- and 16-Bit Integrals

```
short x = 1, y = 1;
short z = x + y; // Compile-time error
```

Comment: So what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx).

> The following assignment statement will produce a compilation error, because the arithmetic expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator evaluates to int by default.

Since there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `short`, you have to do

```
short z = (short) (x + y);
```

Comment: thank you, so why we sometimes use short and byte variables ?

Comment: byte arrays are very useful for IO. A byte represents a small packet of data. As far as I can tell there is no point in `short` in C# or java at all. I never use it.

Comment: @NourAhmed This is probably a better answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1541484/3973077

Comment: It seems the road is still long to learn the language I love to understand, thanks to you my friend has informed me

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you cast the result, the point is: shorts are 16 bits number, hence a short can have a value between **-32.768 and 32.767**, but when you do short x = 5; you are actually assigning an integer as literal

Adding 2 integers can for sure overflow the shorts capacity, hence the complains of the ide...